# Rails submitting form via remote: true on Safari (Safari only) fails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, safari

My forms are submitted via `remote: true` in Chrome and Firefox flawlessly. However, on Safari (desktop and mobile) the form isn't submitted at all. The network 'freezes' in processing status - http://take.ms/IdPyw
It is very similar to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32440), however it's not related to file inputs alone.

My code below:

Form:

```
=form_with(model: Request.new, class: 'g-form g-contact__form', id: 'form', remote: true) do |f|
      =f.file_field :attachments, class: 'g-input__field-file', multiple: true          
      =f.submit 'Отправить', class: 'g-btn g-btn_submit', id: 'form_submit', data: { "disable-with": "Отправляем..." }
```

My `controllers/requests_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    allow_send = true

    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    if allow_send
      respond_to do |format|
        if @request.save
            format.js
          RequestMailer.notify_admin(@request).deliver_now
        else
          format.js { render partial: 'fail' }
        end
      end
    else
      @request.errors.add(:bot, "К сожалению, у нас подозрение, что вы бот. Попробуйте заполнить форму ещё раз.")
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render partial: 'fail' }
        format.html
      end

    end
  end
```

My `create.js.rb`:

```
$('#form-popup').toggle();
$('#success-popup').toggle();
```

If I switch towards more classic approach, meaning responding via html and redirecting to a specific page, the form works in Safari. However, I need the form to work exactly like it works now in Chrome.

My plan B approach would be to rewrite all the code, responsible for submitting the form and checking for errors in plain JS (i.e. `$.ajax({type: "POST",` etc...), however I would really like to stay with tools, provided by rails.

Is there a workaround for Safari?

**Update:**
I was able to retrieve an error message. It states: `Failed to load resource: Network connection lost` (screenshot - http://take.ms/yrAMI)

Comment: Can you post your web inspector network tab logs referring to this request?

Comment: My headers are - http://take.ms/gBEPB

Comment: @seethrough Any chance you could suggest something? This issue is really bothering me :(

Comment: have you had ability to see my messages sent straight to you?

Comment: @seethrough I do see them, already answered you